# Entity framework Leer un archivo Excel y mostrar en datagrid en c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de leer un archivo excel con entity framework , tengo una clase la cual deseo q se vaya llenando con los datos del archivo excel y al final me muestre el excel en un datagrid c#. cual es la manera de hacerlo ? xfavor

```
  private void btnAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog doc = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Microsoft Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (doc.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader fs = File.OpenText(doc.FileName);
                string s;
                while (!fs.EndOfStream)
                {
                    s = fs.ReadLine();
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s); //Aqui me genera error ya que me dice que primero debe agregar columnas
                }
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, al decir *cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo* dejas lugar a opiniones y tu pregunta corre peligro de ser cerrada. Para que no pase esto, te recomiendo editarla agregando los segmentos de código con los que has tenido avance y los mensajes de error, con esto no dejas a lugar a dudas y estarías atacando un problema puntual al que más de un usuario te podrá ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework en principio no tiene relacion con la lectura de un excel, salvo que consigas la implementacion de un provider que se pueda utilizar, se que existe pero no es de libre uso, esta licenciado.

Es por eso que deebrias usar ado.net simple, o quizas alguna libreria basada en `open xml`

Si es con ado.net podria ser algo como

[Read Data From an Excel File (.xls)](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=138)

la idea esta en definir el connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Sample1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0
```

Para despues realizar la consulta al excel como si fuera una db

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
oledbConn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oleda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

pero no estarias usando entity framework sino solo ado.net

Si ado.net no te convence y quieres evaluar una libreria recomendaria

[ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML)